# Using SharePoint 2010 as a support forum

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I was wondering if there are any specific tools to use in SharePoint 2010 to create a support forum/StackOverFlow type of Q&A forum. I know that there is tooling to make a discussion board:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/create-a-discussion-board-HA010086728.aspx

But I do not know of any other kind of tools. Also, are there limitations to doing something like this is SharePoint 2010 (important things that cannot be done in SharePoint in this regard)?

If anyone has had any experience doing something like this that would be a huge help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint 2010 discussion board can be used in this matter, but you have to think about authentication: How are people going to authenticate with you SharePoint portal? You can implement a new authentication provider, or you only use Active Directory, or you use LiveID, Facebook / ....

Office 365 will make this a lot easier with the out-of-the-box integration with LiveID.

But, yes, you can create a support forum in SharePoint! Using taxonomy you can replicate the tagging used here at SO.